# Как в Python записать текстовый файл через FTP, оставив окончание строк вида CRLF (windows-style)?

Tags: python, windows, ftp

Вот этот код должен работать, но на выходе всё равно получаем файл, где убраны символы CR (\r). Остаётся только LF (\n).

```
file = io.open(name, 'r', newline='')
ftp.storlines("STOR " + "name.txt", file)
```

Использовал версию Python 2.7 , т.к. в 3 версии storlines работает только с бинарными данными.

[image: исходные данные]

[image: выходные данные]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам не нужно заменять окончания строк, то используйте бинарный режим (как байты файл отправляйте):

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, file)
```

В этом случае исходная кодировка текста файла также сохраняется.